# onbackpress app got crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have three activites A,B and C,now what i am doing is,From Activity A i am sending one data to B

Activity B

```
   Intent intent=getIntent();
    userids= intent.getStringExtra("userid");
    System.out.println("USERID BC"+userids);
    pname = intent.getStringExtra("names");
    occasions = intent.getStringExtra("oca");
    System.out.println("OC BC"+occasions);
    pics = intent.getStringExtra("photo");
    dates = intent.getStringExtra("datess");
    realtions = intent.getStringExtra("realations");
    friendid = intent.getStringExtra("friendid");

    System.out.println("Frnd BC"+friendid+userids);
    sendgift=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wishfriend_sendgift);
    ImageView propic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wishfriend_propic);
    username=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wishfriend_name);
    ocasions=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wishfriend_occasion);
    datess=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wishfriend_dates);
    pointshori=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.pointshori);
    yourLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearhori);
    selectedpoints=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wishfrindselectdpoints);
    username.setText(pname);
    ocasions.setText(occasions);
    datess.setText("Date: " + dates);
    aQuery.id(propic).image(pics, true, true, 0, R.drawable.male);



    PLACE_URL = "http:///webservices/wish_friend.php?user_id="+userids+"&det="+friendid+"&occ="+ URLEncoder.encode(realtions);
    WISHU_URL = "http:///webservices/wish_friend.php?user_id="+userids;
    sendgift.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(edtmessages.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if(giftpointss.toString().equals("0"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry you can not gift with 0 points",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
            }

        }
    });



        new LoadAllPreset().execute();



        new LoadPlacestatus().execute();
```

that is working fine,now i am going to B to C,but when i come back from C to B my app got crash,,getting null pointer exception

here

```
PLACE_URL = "http:///webservices/wish_friend.php?user_id="+userids+"&det="+friendid+"&occ="+ URLEncoder.encode(realtions);
```

Comment: post full code with logcat

Comment: Where u are starting Activity C?

Comment: If you are trying to access intent data even while coming back from C->B, there it may throw null pointer exception as in "realtions = intent.getStringExtra("realations");", intent is null as you are coming back by back button click.

Comment: how to solve that??i agrre with you

Comment: You can make it static in B activity and update it from other activities, or save it in shared preferences and use wherever required. Also, you can just check the intent if not null before getting the intent values. This will avoid the crash.

Comment: what do you mean with static??

Comment: You can just check the intent if not null before getting the intent values, by "if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)". This will avoid the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check before accessing intent data

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null){
      // intent has data
      Intent intent=getIntent();
      userids= intent.getStringExtra("userid");
      ...
}
else
{
      //probably you are from C->B after back press
}
```

Comment: but then how can i run my asynctask??